# How does multi-language support work in a platform like Drupal 8?

Tags: drupal, joomla, content-management-system, multilingual, drupal-8

I am attempting to scope a website for a client who wants to have a site that will feature multiple language options. They also want it to be a CMS. I am reading that core initiatives for platforms like Joomla, Drupal, etc. are multi-language support, but I am wondering exactly how this works.

My question is on how the translated content gets generated and delivered within these platforms. Would these platforms just check for a language code, then based off that code, print out the Japanese version of the node? The English version of the node? So essentially, for however many languages I'd like to have, I'd have to create an individual page (node) for that specific language that mirrors say, English? So an install with a 10 English pages would also need the same 10 pages with nodes for the Japanese version?

For the admin's sake, would I be better off just setting up multiple Drupal installs in different subdomains or something? So the Japanese admin would visit jp.mysite.com/user and only have access to the Japanese database? And same for the English admin?

I guess essentially what I am asking, is if it is better to just duplicate my install on multiple boxes, or have one install on one box with a bunch of "duplicate nodes" that essentially mirror each other, but have different languages within them?

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak to Drupal, but with Joomla - there are languages you can install on the backend (which are pulled from community added locale files I believe)

When you do switch it, you should see a message like "Default Language Saved".

This does not affect users that have chosen a specific language on their profile or on the login page.

However, when using the multilanguage functionality (i.e. when the plugin System - Languagefilter is enabled) the Site Default Language has to also be a published Content language.

So ultimately - use one install. Multiple installs would be a bit silly - especially considering these CMS are designed to have that functionality.

Answer (score 0):

For Drupal, my recommendation would be creating only one site with multilingual support. You have the ability of deciding how you want your site to behave when there is no translation, like showing the original node, or hiding the page completely from the users if you have different menus per language.

Administration would be easier, and content edition probably too.

You can still use subdomains per language if you want to with a single site, that's a feature out of the box with Drupal. You can set up that in the language negotiation page, which is quite flexible in terms of how to perform negotiation of the content and interface languages you want to use.